# How create responsive slider with position relative and absolute?

Tags: css, slider

Im trying to build simple fadeIn-Out slider. 
How to have responsive slides and stacked at the same time? Maybe there is another solution for this problem (I mean: not using position relative/absolute)?

I use parent element with "position relative" and slides with "position absolute" to stack them one on the top of another (then I can use opacity to fade between slides). The problem is that slides are not responsive. If I remove "position relative" from parent element slides are resizing, but they ignore parent element and fill the whole screen.

```
     body {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
     }
     .slides {
        position: relative;
      }
     .slides li img {
       width: 100%;
       position:absolute;
       height: auto;
       top:0;
       left:0;
     }

    <div id="microslider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li><img src="slides/slide-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="slides/slide-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="slides/slide-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li><img src="slides/slide-4.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello, you mean something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/foffka/c0wjfd6j/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/qsyxR/

Comment: That’s right, just responsive

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to create the slides you can take this jsfiddles as references: [jsfiddle.net/foffka/c0wjfd6j](http://jsfiddle.net/foffka/c0wjfd6j) and [jsfiddle.net/kidino/qsyxR](http://jsfiddle.net/kidino/qsyxR)
2. Regarding the subject of 'responsive', there are several possibilities, depends what you want.

   - I recommend you to set a width to the `.slides li`.
   - You already wrote `width: 100%; height: auto;` inside the `.slides li img`. That means the image will adapt to the 100% of the width of its parent.   If you set, for example `li` to `300px`, every image will adapt to this value.
   - If you want that each image have a width of 50% of the device width, set `50vw` inside the `li` selector and see what happens when you resize the page.
   - If you want that in mobile (for example 480px and less) every image have 100% of device width, you can set:

```
    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        .slides li {
            width: 100vw;
        }
    }
```

Also you can play with the min-width and max-width values. And so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Nico, but I found the problem: if I remove "width: 960px;" from body or replace it with "max-width:960px;" slider becomes responsive. But I still dont think its real solution as in many cases I use "width" in body (or anybody who would like to try my slider)

Comment: Try this: remove the `width: 960px` style from the body and set it in  #microslider, which is the wrapper of your slider.